# Matches from re-builder different from re-search-forward and search-forward-regexp due to double backslash

Tags: regular-expressions

Following [Org mode refiling gobbles a newline and absorbs the next heading](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53526/org-mode-refiling-gobbles-a-newline-and-absorbs-the-next-item) where Org mode refiling has gobbled some of the next heading, I want to search for those gobbled headings where the stars are not preceded by newlines. I wrote this regular expression with `re-builder`:

```
[^
\\*]\\*
```

It shows 16 matches and I confirmed that some are relevant. But `search-forward-regexp` with the same expression matches every character. I suspected it was due to escaping the backslash in the `re-builder` literal, which uses double-quotes, and `search-forward-regexp` with

```
[^
\*]\*
```

works to find lone stars.

I did not see double backlashes in the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html).

Why does this happen, and when do backslashes need to be escaped?

Comment: Does the related Q&A https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568/454 answer this for you?  I suspect that you are using `search-forward-regexp` interactively, in which case your regexps need to be in `string` syntax rather than `read` syntax.

Comment: Also note that within a character alternative (square brackets) `\ ` is a literal backslash, so the regexp `[^\*]\*` matches any character *except a backslash or an asterisk*, followed by an asterisk.