# Error when loading new version of org mode

Tags: org-mode, git, version-compatibilty

I upgraded Org-mode to the latest version on the master branch (according to [How to install latest version of org mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/how-to-install-latest-version-of-org-mode?noredirect=1#comment86555_55324)) and now I get this error every few seconds:

```
Error running timer ‘org-indent-initialize-agent’: (void-function org-time-
add) [8 times]
```

When I run `org-version`, I get `9.1.9`, instead of the `9.3.3` from the master branch; yet I don't have this problem with just my local version.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the culprit in opening org files before loading the new version:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/code/org-mode/lisp")
(require 'org-loaddefs)
```

In a comment in that thread, I mentioned that the above loading commands failed to load `9.3.3` if I ran `(org-version)` first, so I suspect that running any org command fixes the Org version to the built-in version of org mode and that loading a more recent version introduces compatibility issues.

When I run the code to load the new Org version before any other Org command, org mode runs fine.

See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/how-to-install-latest-version-of-org-mode/55415#55415) for details on the mixed installation of built-in and latest versions:

> The main idea is that you need to make sure that Org mode is set up,
>   using the new bits that you downloaded only. Emacs comes with a
>   version of Org mode bundled up with it, but that is inevitably older
>   than what is available from the Org mode git repo. It is important to
>   avoid loading any piece from the bundled up version or else you might
>   end up with a "mixed" installation (there are many hits for that on
>   the Org mode mailing list).
>
> As I mention in a comment, and @Tobias has verified in another
>   comment, you do not need to byte-compile the new version - you only
>   need to make autoloads. That creates an org-loaddefs.el file, so that
>   all the common entry points into org will, when first invoked, load
>   the appropriate file first. It is important ... to set the load-path before loading the
>   org-loaddefs.el file: otherwise, you may end up with the dreaded
>   "mixed" install I mentioned above.