# org-agenda-redo: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-let

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

The error happens with the cursor in *org agenda view* and I want the next span displayed.

Can anyone make sense of the debugger?

I can't but only guess. Searching my init.el for `org-let` or `org-agenda` doesn't lead to any clues.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-let)
  org-let(nil (org-agenda-list 'nil nil 'week nil))
  org-agenda-redo()
  org-agenda-later(1)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda-later 1)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-later nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda-later)
```

---

Edit:
`list-load-path-shadows` excerpt:

```
/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/develop/org-20210920/org-macs hides /usr/share/emacs/28.1/lisp/org/org-macs
/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/develop/org-20210920/org-agenda hides /usr/share/emacs/28.1/lisp/org/org-agenda
```

Comment: Function `org-let` isn't defined. You need to load the library that defines that function. If it's defined as part of Org then you might need to update to a more recent Org version.

Comment: This is no doubt a duplicate question. Search for "void-function" and you'll find it, I expect.

Comment: What version of Org mode are you running? Is it the version that comes with your emacs? If not, how do you install Org mode? `org-let` is defined in `org-agenda.el` - it was introduced in Org mode 9.4.5 I believe. You may have a somewhat curdled installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when loading new version of org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/error-when-loading-new-version-of-org-mode)

Comment: @NickD Org mode version 9.5.2

Comment: You probably have a curdled installation where you are getting some bits from one place and some from another. The answer below contains some useful hints for you to try.

Comment: So yes, you are probably getting some bits from the 20210920 package of Org mode and the rest from 28.1. I'd recommend that you uninstall the 20210920 package completely with `M-x package-delete` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a goofed up `org` installation.  Do

1. Do `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET`
2. In the resulting buffer `M-s o org-agenda` and `M-s o org-macs`

The paths that you see will give you a clue about what you need to fix.

---

To find `org` version do `M-x org-version`

---

A simple search for `org-let` in `github` in `el` files, suggests that `org-let` was in `org-macs` in the past. See https://github.com/search?q=org-let+extension%3Ael

---

In `org-9.5.4`, `C-h f org-let` gives me

> `org-let` is a compiled Lisp function in `org-agenda.el`.
> This function is obsolete since 2021; use `cl-progv` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Did as you suggested, yet I fail getting the clues out of the `this path hides that path`

Comment: Why don't you post the results after running occur for `org-agenda` and `org-macs`.   Remove any private information from the path.

Comment: Did you try with `emacs -q` and `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Looked at the load path shadows, no clue what the problem could be.  Try removing the directory `/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/develop/org-20210920` entirely, and restart Emacs.  Your agenda should work.  Once you are satisfied iinstall `org-9.5.*` from GNU ELPA.

Comment: Removing the directory as you suggested solved it. I furthermore removed/re-installed `org-superstar`