# org-export options are off

Tags: org-mode, org-export

My org export options become inactive/off. Like the picture below:

[image: screen shot of current org export]

compare to its previous form:

[image]

And the export is not functional. I get the following message:

```
Invalid face reference: org-dispatcher-highlight [66 times] 
org-export-as: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1
```

I don't know why and when it happened, but I guess is there was some update on org package. If you have any idea or any hint how to diagnose the issue, I very much appreciate the input.

Comment: Inactive because you can't see the colors? Did you actually try to do an export? If that works, then the fontification of the buffer is the problem; if not, there is a more fundamental problem. Is there an `Export command: ` prompt in the minibuffer?

Comment: No, it's not functional :( I get the following message: "Invalid face reference: org-dispatcher-highlight [66 times]" and "org-export-as: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1"

Comment: Please add that information to your question: comments are for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually entering the command `org-reload` fixes the issue!

Comment: ... or restart emacs - particularly when `org-reload` barfs (which *will* happen).

Comment: Strangely, that didn't solve (unless I have it in the init files)

Comment: "...unless I have it in the init files": what does *it* refer to in this sentence?

Comment: "It" refers to ``org-reload``.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need `org-reload` in your init file. Are you sure you are not loading Org mode from multiple places, ending up with a "mixed" installation. See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/error-when-loading-new-version-of-org-mode/55411#55411) for some hints.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, that could be the case, as I recently made some updates. I'll certainly check this out.